# How to manipulate the output stream directly? (Was: why it's not increment value of increment operator in case of assignment in c?)

Tags: c, obfuscation

I fixed the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16611401/315052) so that it would compile:

```
#define text ();
#define return &argv;return
int *** emphasized () {
    static int x, *argv = &x, **xpp = &argv;
    puts("\r10 11 11");
    return &xpp;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int a;
    int n = 10;
    printf("%d",n);
      n++;
    printf("%d",n);
     a = n++;
    printf("%d",n);***emphasized text***
    return 0;
}
```

In the original question, the asker said:

> Output= 10 11 11 why it's not increment value of n in second increment operator

Which is why `emphasized()` does something funny. I was trying to come up with a way that took the asker's literal code to make it do what he/she said it did. To that end, I treated the `***emphasized text***` as part of the source.

*My* question is: How would `emphasized()` be changed so that it renders the `10 11 11` output without calling any output function? I am hoping to observe a way to alter the output rendered by the `printf()` to standard output to add the spaces but botch the last number.

Since this question is labeled with obfuscation, if the solution involves adding more `#define`s, have at it.

Comment: what makes you think the increment doesn't happen ? If it's the output, then that's simply because that's what the `puts` call outputs.

Comment: Why did you remove the line `#define printf(a,b) (void)0`?

Comment: @JohnBode: Didn't need it to get the observed output.

Comment: @user315052: Yes you did; if you run the program again, you will *definitely* get different output.

Comment: @JohnBode: If redirected to a file, but not if observed on the console.

Comment: @user315052: I'm an idiot; I thought I saw a newline character in the last `printf` call (my eyes don't work so well anymore).  But the point is, that line you deleted effectively commented out the calls to `printf`; if you put it back in, you would get the same output to the console and to a file.

Comment: This depends on what kind of console you use.

Comment: The `\r` a carriage return does the magic.

Comment: I thought this was a question about c/c++ obfuscation, not about stack overflow question obfuscation.  It's tough to give an accurate answer if you keep changing the question!

Comment: @Arunas, sorry about that. I have already up voted your answer. Not much more I can do than that, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the original code:

```
#define text ();
#define printf(a,b) (void)0
#define return &argv;return
int *** emphasized () {
    static int x, *argv = &x, **xpp = &argv;
    puts("\r10 11 11");
    return &xpp;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int a;
    int n = 10;
    printf("%d",n);
      n++;
    printf("%d",n);
     a = n++;
    printf("%d",n);***emphasized text***
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the code after being run through the preprocessor:

```
int *** emphasized () {
    static int x, *argv = &x, **xpp = &argv;
    puts("\r10 11 11");
    &argv;return &xpp;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int a;
    int n = 10;
    (void)0;
      n++;
    (void)0;
     a = n++;
    (void)0;***emphasized ();***
    &argv;return 0;
}
```

Note that the `printf` statements don't appear in the preprocessed code; the value of `n` isn't being displayed to the console *at all* in this version.  The output comes from the `emphasized` function.

Answer (score 2):

`n` is incremented to `12` but as `n` is never printed its value doesn't matter.

Run that crap through the preprocessor and you'll see why.

There is a `#define` that voids all the `printf` statements.

The actual output comes from the `puts` in `emphasized`.

Answer (score 1):

n is incremented twice, and it is also printed out, exactly as you'd expect.

But `text` has been `#defined` to be a pair of parentheses and a semicolon: `();`, and `return` is replaced with `&argv;return`

So the code

```
***emphasized text***
return 0;
```

becomes:

```
***emphasized();***
&argv;return 0;
```

or slightly less oddly formatted:

```
***emphasized();
***&argv;
return 0;
```

so the printfs do exactly what it looks like they're going to do, and then `emphasized()` is called, and it backs up the cursor with a '\r'  (carriage return, no line feed) and prints out your 10 11 11.

All the asterisks are just for show, dereferencing pointers but not using the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly less obfuscated version that remaps each `printf()` call to something that ends up constructing the output as described by the original asker. It is slightly more straightforward since it doesn't define a silly `emphasized()` function. It also avoids unnecessarily dereferencing `argv`, to avoid undefined behavior in the case that `argc` is 0.

This version also has the property that the program will also behave as the asker described if the `***emphasized text***` string is removed from the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define printf(f,x) printf(x>11?"%d\n":"%d ", x>11?x-1:x);
#define emphasized &argv;
#define text if(0)
#define return &argv;return
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int a;
    int n = 10;
    printf("%d",n);
      n++;
    printf("%d",n);
     a = n++;
    printf("%d",n);***emphasized text***
    return 0;
}
```